# Tensorflow 2.x custom loss function on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

### Problem

I am trying to write a custom loss function for my Tensorflow 2 model. I have written the following function that calculates the loss I am seeking when I manually pass in an input and output Tensor.

```py
def on_off_balance_loss(y_true: EagerTensor, y_pred: EagerTensor) -> float:
    y_true_array: ndarray = np.asarray(y_true).flatten()
    y_predict_array: ndarray = np.asarray(y_pred).flatten()

    on_delta: float = 0.999

    on_loss: float = 0
    off_loss: float = 0
    on_count: int = 0
    off_count: int = 0

    for i in range(len(y_true_array)):
        loss: float = cell_loss(y_true_array[i], y_predict_array[i])
        if y_true_array[i] > on_delta:
            on_count += 1
            on_loss = on_loss * ((on_count - 1) / on_count) + (loss / on_count)
        else:
            off_count += 1
            off_loss = off_loss * ((off_count - 1) / off_count) + (loss / off_count)

    on_factor: int = 4
    return (on_factor * on_loss + off_loss) / (on_factor + 1)
```

For context, `y_true` consists of a 2D matrix of 1's and 0's as floats, where 0's are much more common. As such, my model was getting a good loss value by just getting most of the 0's correct, even though where the 1's are is the more important metric. This custom loss puts more proportional emphasis on the location of the 1's.

I changed `model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy")` to `model.compile(loss=on_off_balance_loss)` in the attempt to use the new loss function. This doesn't seem to work, as the loss function is supposed to take in [an entire batch of data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile). So, I tried something like this with `model.compile(loss=on_off_balance_batch_loss)`:

```py
def on_off_balance_batch_loss(y_true, y_pred) -> float:
    y_trues: list = tf.unstack(y_true)
    y_preds: list = tf.unstack(y_pred)
    loss: float = 0

    for i in range(0, len(y_trues)):
        loss = loss * (i / (i + 1)) + (on_off_balance_loss(y_trues[i], y_preds[i]) / (i + 1))

    return loss
```

This doesn't work. The shape of `y_true` is `(None, None, None)`, and the shape of `y_pred` is `(None, X, Y)`, where `X` and `Y` are the dimensions of the 2D array of 1's and 0's.

I am working in Google Colaboratory. However, locally, `np.asarray()` seems to work in the way that throws an error on Colaboratory. So, I'm not really sure if the error lies in my loss function or with some setup thing in Colaboratory. I have ensured that I am using Tensorflow 2.3.0 both locally and on Colaboratory.

### EDITS:

I tried adding `run_eagerly=True` to `model.compile()` and using `.numpy()` instead of `np.asarray()` in `on_off_balance_loss()`. This changed the type of input in `on_off_balance_batch_loss` from `Tensor` to `EagerTensor`. This leads to the error `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/kernel:0', 'lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'lstm_4/lstm_cell_4/kernel:0', 'lstm_4/lstm_cell_4/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_4/lstm_cell_4/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0', 'lstm_5/lstm_cell_5/kernel:0', 'lstm_5/lstm_cell_5/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_5/lstm_cell_5/bias:0'].`. The same error occurs if I use

```py
def on_off_balance_batch_loss(y_true: EagerTensor, y_pred: EagerTensor) -> float:
    y_trues = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False).unstack(y_true)
    y_preds = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False).unstack(y_pred)

    loss: float = 0.0
    i: int = 0

    for tensor in range(y_trues.size()):
        elem_loss: float = on_off_balance_loss(y_trues.read(i), y_preds.read(i))
        loss = loss * (i / (i + 1)) + (elem_loss / (i + 1))
        i += 1

    return loss
```

and omit `run_eagerly=True`. Even before the errors are reached, it seems that the whole program is running slower that when I used a default loss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out the solution is a lot more simple than what I was trying above. Below is the style in which such a function should be implemented. I compared it to the output of my original function, `on_off_balance_loss`, and it matches.

```py
def on_off_equal_loss(y_true: Tensor, y_pred: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    on_delta: float = 0.99

    on_mask: Tensor = tf.greater_equal(y_true, on_delta)
    off_mask: Tensor = tf.less(y_true, on_delta)

    on_loss: Tensor = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(
        y_true[on_mask], y_pred[on_mask]
    ))), tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(on_mask), tf.float32))

    off_loss: Tensor = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(
        y_true[off_mask], y_pred[off_mask]
    ))), tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(off_mask), tf.float32))

    on_factor: float = 4.0
    return tf.divide(tf.add(tf.multiply(on_factor, on_loss), off_loss), on_factor + 1.0)
```